# Kubernetes in vmware vsphere issues

Tags: kubernetes, fabric8

I am following [this guide](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/vsphere/) to set up my cluster. It all works fine.
However, when I install fabric8 in this cluster I run out of disk on the minions. The image, `kube.vmdk`, is only about 6GB. It is the `/var/lib/docker` which gets filled up. How do I solve this?

Using the GUI for vmware the option to resize the disk is 'greyed out'.

Should I attach a second disk to the minions and then mount this disk? Where should I mount it? `/var/lib/docker`?

I would appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0):

Docker's image is store in /var/lib/docker(more precisely, it store in storage driver's directory, /var/lib/docker/aufs when using aufs storage driver) , so when Kubernetes report  disk gets filled up, it check that directory. 
So you can

1. Remove all the images in docker(not necessary, you can copy everything to new dir).
2. stop docker daemon.
3. mount your new disk to /var/lib/docker/ or /var/lib/docker
4. start docker daemon.

If you are not sure what storage driver your docker is using, type `docker info` in your node, will get something contain this:

```
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 139
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you run out of the space of the disk. You can remove all the files in `/var/lib/docker`, and mount the second disk. Finally you need restart your dockerd.